# Как изменить тип свойства (поля) пользователя в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно изменить тип этого свойства с Строка на Выпадающий список, в который будут подтягиваться должности из отдельного инфоблока?

Comment: Установи тип свойства "привязка к элементам"

Comment: Я не нашел, где это можно сделать. Подскажете?